# Calculate the interquartile range of probability density function. With more information attached

Tags: calculus, probability, functions

[image]

[image]

I have been trying to figure out the last part of this question and have tried I will add the work below but I can’t seem to figure it out I am self studying so I have no teacher to ask. Any help would be much appreciated . Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Please format using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quartiles must satisfy $0 \le x \le 5$.

The lower quartile is $\frac{10-\sqrt{100-25}}{2}\approx 0.69$ (this appears in your calculations but is not the value you chose)

while the upper quartile would be $\frac{10-\sqrt{100-75}}{2}= 2.5$ (you divided by $8$ rather than $4$)